# How to use mod_rewrite in httpd.conf file to remove .php extensions?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I know that there are countless examples online of how to use mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file to remove .php extensions. I found this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

And this worked perfectly when I used it in a .htaccess file in my root directory.

Now I'm trying to switch to doing my rewrites in the httpd.conf configuration file on the server instead of htaccess. I copied and pasted that exact code into the file, wrapping it in an `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>` tag (the tutorial I followed said to do this.)

But now the rewrite doesn't work; when I try to follow links on my website that worked before the change, Apache gives me an object not found error.

I know that mod_rewrite is working and I'm putting the code in the right place and everything, because I have the rule

```
RewriteRule ^/echo/(.*)$ /retired/echosomething.php?string=$1
```

just after the other rewrite lines and this line works.

What do I need to do differently to make mod_rewrite work without the .php extensions? Why did this code work in htaccess but not in httpd.conf?

Comment: Is the module loaded when the rewrite rules are supposed to be loaded? Order matters in configs.

Comment: yes, I tried to make that clear by saying that my second RewriteRule line worked but the first one didn't.